# List raw with Details - android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

Now i'm building app with custom list view to support more than device scale

This is my code to do that

**list_raw**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/table_2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="77dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="1/12/2013"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/match"
     android:layout_width="116dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="49dip"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="40dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:src="@drawable/pic" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="12dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Ahly"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dip" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:text="VS"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="49dip"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:src="@drawable/pic" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="12dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="liverpool"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dip" />

     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/place"
     android:layout_width="46dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Out"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="76dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="Aljazeera"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

please i need all of text and images to be at the center of each part of view

Comment: i can not add screen shots for this problem cause i still new here :)

Comment: You can't set orientation for Relative Layout... Because its work as a drop- down functionality

Comment: @Piyush Gupta , can you explain more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Aljazeera"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Out"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ahly"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Vs" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Liverpool"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="1/12/2013"
        android:textColor="#000" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: result for your code is :  http://store1.up-00.com/2013-12/1386073633881.png ,, target : http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176413.png ,, is there any thing missing ?

Comment: yes , first image is the result for your code on Samsung note

Comment: and you must change your main layout in which you are inflating custom_list..... according to custom_list.xml layout file

Comment: http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386078499251.png ,,, this is the result for your code after little edits :)

Comment: it is very very useful :) but sure i will need your help in the next steps :)

Comment: @MohammedGomaa Ok sure..I will be

Comment: how are you :) , please i need your help to make my app support Arabic and English languages
- is i need to create new layouts ? or try to redesign current layouts because default alignments for Arabic is right and English is left

Comment: is there another way to chat with you ?

Comment: how :) , can you get me your email?

Comment: it's not appear to me

Comment: i tried to add all have Piyush Gupta name :) is this write way to meet you ? :D

Comment: piyush.gupta569@gmail.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397631/change-layouts-for-all-activities-from-one-acticity/20397789?noredirect=1#20397789 ,, can you help please

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/table_2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="77dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="1/12/2013"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/match"
     android:layout_width="116dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="49dip"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="40dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:src="@drawable/pic" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="12dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Ahly"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dip" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:text="VS"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="49dip"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:src="@drawable/pic" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="12dip"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="liverpool"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="10dip" />

     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/place"
     android:layout_width="46dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Out"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="76dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="Aljazeera"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks @Tamilan but my background for list raw have vertical lines and i need to set my data between this lines , in hdpi works fine but in xhdpi texts in the middle not at the correct place

Comment: @MohammedGomaa Then better have a plain background and insert lines whereever necessary in xml itself.. that ll work and suit far better..

Comment: please check this images // for hdpi --> http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176261.png /// for xhdpi --> http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176332.png /// target design --> http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176413.png

Comment: @MohammedGomaa ya.. thats why i am saying try to give those vertical lines in xml itself.. else if you try to align your design according to your image with vertical lines you might face weird issues for differnt density screens..

Comment: Thanks @Tamilan , I know and understand what you mean but can help me for how to do that

Comment: @Mohammed Gomaa You should use views with color background for lines not a drawable image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this but change image resources to yours..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="77dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1/12/2013"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/match"
        android:layout_width="116dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="49dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="12dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ahly"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="VS"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="49dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="12dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="liverpool"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="46dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Out"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="76dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Aljazeera"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Mohammed Gomaa sorry but i think its completing ur requirement when I saw that layout.

Comment: Thanks @keshav for your reply but my code results that // hdpi --> http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176261.png // xhdpi --> http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176332.png // target view must to like this --> http://store2.up-00.com/2013-12/1386068176413.png // can you help me about that please ?

Comment: I think you should remove relative layout and use only linear layouts ,It should help.